# Successful Payment Redirection not working

Tags: payment-gateway, flutterwave

I my international payment script refuses to accept international payment on some cards in dollars but charges my Ghana bank card in dollars as desired. Also, how do I get to a redirect link after transaction.
Below is my code (without my API Keys of course)

````
const API_publicKey = " ";

function payWithRave() {
    var x = getpaidSetup({
        PBFPubKey: API_publicKey,
        customer_email: "wwackuaku@yahoo.com",
        amount: 0,
        customer_phone: "233244631868",
        currency: "GHS",
        country: "GH",
        payment_options: "card",
        custom_logo: "https://ananseman.com/assets/images/masks.png",
        txref: "rave-1543925647",
        meta: [{
            metaname: "GHsupportID",
            metavalue: "SP1234"
        }],
        onclose: function() {},
        callback: function(response) {
            var txref = response.tx.txRef; // collect txRef returned and pass to a                     server page to complete status check.
            console.log("This is the response returned after a charge", response);
            if (
                response.tx.chargeResponseCode == "00" ||
                response.tx.chargeResponseCode == "0"
            ) {
                // redirect to a success page
            } else {
                // redirect to a failure page.
            }

            x.close(); // use this to close the modal immediately after payment.
        }
    });
}
</script>```
````

Answer (score 1):

Make the currency dynamic so that users can choose the currency they want to be charged, then pass the currency to your payload.....`currency: "USD"` or `currency: "GHS"`

For the redirect_url, specify a redirect_url in your payload

`redirect_url: "http://www.example.com"`